# Can I make slideToggle() overlap a div rather than move it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website that I am making with a friend and there is a problem where, when  a dropdown tab is being slideToggle()'d with jquery, it moves the html div below it, and I just want it to overlap it, is there an easy way to do it?

**Here is my html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-JAW99MJVpJBGcbzEuXk4Az05s/XyDdBomFqNlM3ic+I="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Annie+Use+Your+Telescope|Architects+Daughter|Coda|Indie+Flower|Shadows+Into+Light|Special+Elite" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>ALFEX Inc.</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='header'>
            <h1>ALFEX INCORPORATED</h1>


            <ul class='tabsbar'>
                <a class='link' href='alfex.html'><li class='tab'>Home</li></a>
                <div class='link'><li class='tab' id='gam'>Gags & Memes</li></div>
                <div class='link'><li class='tab' id='crew'>The Crew</li></div>
                <a class='link' href='alfex-codex.html'><li class='tab'>The Codex</li></a>
                <a class='link' href='alfex-minigames.html'><li class='tab'>Minigames</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class='panel-gam'>
            <ul class='panel-list'>
                <a class='p-link' href='alfex-gagsandmemes-doggo.html'><li class='p-tab'>Doggo Memes</li></a>
                <a class='p-link' href='alfex-gagsandmemes-dad.html'><li class='p-tab'>Dad Jokes</li></a>
                <a class='p-link' href='alfex-gagsandmemes-pun.html'><li class='p-tab'>Puns</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class='panel-crew'>
            <ul class='panel-list'>
                <a class='p-link' href='alfex-alfie.html'><li class='p-tab'>Alfie</li></a>
                <a class='p-link' href='alfex-alex.html'><li class='p-tab'>Alex</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class='main'>
            <h2>Welcome to the Alfex Inc. website</h2>

            <h3>for all your cousin needs xD.</h3>

            <div class='olexparent'>
                <iframe class='olexvideo' width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aa6IGzjY_kI?list=PLsCWhnzJYhqRCjHKprzyP7vQBJexv6OOZ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen align="right"></iframe>
            </div>

            <p class="intro"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my JavaScript Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.content').fadeIn(800);

    $('#gam').click(function() {
        $('.panel-crew').slideUp(0);
        $('.panel-gam').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#crew').click(function() {
        $('.panel-gam').slideUp(0);
        $('.panel-crew').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**If needed, here is my CSS:**

```
/* * {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
} */

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('http://images.naldzgraphics.net/2012/08/4-lined.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.tabsbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #525c68;
}

.tab {
    padding: 18px 0px 18px 0px;
    float: left;
    max-width: 20%;
    min-width: 20%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #525c68;
    color: #5dbace;
}

.header {
    display: block;
    background-color: #525c68;
}

.link{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #525c68;
    color: #7bcadb;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', 'Coda', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 550%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #525c68;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Annie Use Your Telescope', 'Indie Flower', 'Shadows Into Light', 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
    font-size: 24px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', 'Annie Use Your Telescope', cursive;
    padding: 0px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.main {
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0px 10% 180px 10%;
    padding: 80px 80px 100px 80px;
}

h3, .minigames-subheading, .minigames-subheading2, .alfie-subheading {
    opacity: 0.5;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    font-style:  italic;
    font-family: 'Coda', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 50%;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.olexvideo {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 59px;
    max-width: 52%;
}

.panel-gam {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #525c68;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    width: 20%;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
}

.panel-crew {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #525c68;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    width: 20%;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: 40%;
}

.p-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', 'Coda', sans-serif;
    padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.panel-list {
    padding: 0px 40px 10px 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a.p-link:hover {
    color: #d8d8d8;
}

h4 {
    font-family: 'Special Elite', 'Annie Use Your Telescope', cursive;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #737373;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.rockpaperscissors {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 20px 20px 60px 20px;
    background: #a6a6a6;
    border-color: #a6a6a6;
    min-height: 300px;
}

button {
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: #4f5864;
    background-color: #525c68;
    color: #7bcadb;
    padding: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', 'Coda', sans-serif;
    width: 33%;
    font-size: 28px;
}

button:hover {
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: #73c6d9;
    background-color: #7bcadb;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.result {
    font-family: 'Special Elite', 'Coda', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.reset {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

li.tab:hover {
    background-color: #7bcadb;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.specialised-memes {
    border: none;
    padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
    font-family: 
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ccc;  
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #999;  
}

.page-feed {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1000px;
    max-width: 45%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.left-side {
    width: 520px;
}

.fb-picture {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 393px;
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.embed {
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    width: 50%;
}

.intro {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: use `.panel-gam, .panel-crew { position: absolute; }`

Comment: Yes this works however now I cannot click the tab to slide the panel back up :/

Comment: Yes this works however now I cannot click the tab to slide the panel back up :/

Comment: there are multiple things that needs to be changed to get this work.. follow this [**tutorial**](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_navigation.asp)